# How to create a StreamSupplier for IntStream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So this is the first time me working with Streams in Java. I have first created an IntStream containing 1000 numbers. Now when I did more than one operation I encountered with an error. On further exploring, I learned that Streams are consumed after one traversal and hence we need Suppliers for the same. I tried various methods but I was unable to create a Supplier for the ***IntStream numbers***. I would appreciate all help.
Please note I don't need help creating 1000 random numbers. Instead, I need help creating a Supplier for the IntStream.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ArrayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        IntStream numbers = rand.ints(1000, 1, 11);
        Supplier<Stream<Integer>> streamSupplier = () -> numbers.boxed();
        // The statement below works fine
        streamSupplier.get().forEach(System.out::println);
        // The statement below doesn't works 
        System.out.println(streamSupplier.get().count());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you make a `Supplier<IntStream>`?

Comment: I tried that too but I was unable to.  I did this `Supplier<IntStream> streamSupplier = () -> numbers;` but still got the same type of error.

Comment: Are you _specifically_ trying to return _the same random numbers_?

Comment: No. Any 1000 random numbers in the range will do. The only restriction is that IntStream should be used. Otherwise I could've used Arrays or List.

Comment: Then I suggest that you read up on basic documentation on lambdas. `Supplier<IntStream> i = () -> rand.ints(1000, 1, 11)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had thought of doing it but never tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Supplier<IntStream> streamSupplier = () -> rand.ints(1000,1,11);
```

And if you want to repeat the same numbers, you can set the seed to Random.

```
Supplier<IntStream> streamSupplier = () -> {
       rand.setSeed(23);
       return rand.ints(1000,1,11);
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use stream only once by design. Your supplier returns the same stream each time, so the second usage

```
// The statement below doesn't works 
System.out.println(streamSupplier.get().count());
```

is illegal.

The base for your supplier shoudn't be a stream.
You can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Random rand = new Random();
   List<Integer> numbers = rand.ints(1000, 1, 11).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
   Supplier<Stream<Integer>> streamSupplier = () -> numbers.stream();
   streamSupplier.get().forEach(System.out::println);
   System.out.println(streamSupplier.get().count());
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware that it can be used once. I need a working solution for the above issue.

Comment: @SushantPradhan, if you read the answer further, you'll find it.

Comment: I have been restricted by the question which states that Array objects and List objects must not be used.